# Graphics.DrawImage() to outside the PictureBox, How to show the ScrollBar?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, picturebox

I am trying to draw a number of nearly identical Image with `Graphics.DrawImage()`, taken from a Bitmap, into a `PictureBox` docked into a `Panel` and `Panel.AutoScroll` has been set into `True`. I know they are supposed to clip when they are drawn outside the `PictureBox` bound (by i mean bound is the `PictureBox`'s Width and Height) but let say i can redraw those images when the `PictureBox` is resized, but that is not my real problem.

```
//This is my code which draw 40 x 40 circle, node alike, bitmaps into PictureBox
private void ValButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Graphics gr = picBox.CreateGraphics();
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
    {
        gr.DrawImage(nodeBmp, (imgDisplay.Width / 2) + (i * 20), 80);
    }
    gr.Dispose();
}
```

when  i resize the Form, by stretching the Form or by Maximizing the Form, the `PictureBox` is resized but the image is left not changed, not moved and still clipped, and no ScrollBar shown
[image: There should be 100 circles there]
^There should be 100 circles there, and yet no ScrollBar

[image: I stretch the Window, Still no ScrollBar]
^stretched the Window, Still no ScrollBar. The X and Y label down there shown the current Width and Height of the `PictureBox`

Also, i have tried to change the `PictureBox.SizeMode` to `AutoSize` and `Normal` still no change.

So, are the whole trial i have attempt wrong ? if so, what are the correct way to achieve ScrollBar for a Drawn images with `Graphics` ?

Thank you.

Comment: _Graphics gr = picBox.CreateGraphics();_ this will not work well: Neither will the result be persistent nor can it trigger a scrollbar. Only use the PaintArgs `e.Graphics` object from the `Paint` event!! See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725326/how-to-make-use-of-autoscrollbar-when-drawing-contents-with-gdi) for a solution..!

Comment: @TaW Let's say that i have a method that handle Paint Event of my `picBox`, so then i should do all of my "drawing" with its `e.Graphics`, right ?

Comment: Right. Either directly in the Paint event or in methods to which you pass the e.Graphics object. But mind: Do not try to cache it, only use it triggered right from the Paint event! While drawing beyond the boundaries of the PBox you know the new MinSize and set it..