# How does OnPaint work with a ScrollableControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollable

Simple Windows Forms application with a custom control derived from ScollableControl.  In the control, OnPaint is overridden and a line is drawn from (0,0) to (100,100).

When the vertical scrollbar is slid down, the diagonal line nicely moves out of view.  But when the scrollbar is slid back up, the diagonal line doesn't come back into view properly.  It comes back sort of all chopped up.  See picture below.

Here's the code for the custom control...

```
public partial class CustomControl1 : ScrollableControl
{
    public CustomControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AutoScroll = true;

        AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(1000, 1000);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);

        pe.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

[image: control before and after scrolling vertically]

Comment: `var disp = DisplayRectangle; e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0 + disp.X, 0 + disp.Y, 100 + disp.X, 100 + disp.Y);`. `Invalidate()` on Scroll. Enable double buffering. -- You can also use the `AutoScrollPosition` property.

Comment: Graphics.TranslateTransform() required to offset the drawing by the scroll position.  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8727320/17034).

Comment: The post Hans linked already handles the `AutoScrollPosition` I mentioned. Do you agree it's a duplicate?

Comment: Hans Passant, the example you shared is based on a Form.   The problem I'm having is based on a ScrollableControl.

Comment: A Form IS a ScrollableControl. That's where all AutoScroll... stuff comes from. Including `AutoScrollPosition`. Also where `DisplayRectangle` is overridden.

Comment: Thanks, Jimi.  That did the trick.  Not sure I really understand it, but I got something to chew on. 

In my real application, I override OnPaint inside that ScrollableControl to draw a grid - and I'm now adding those offsets.  But that control also has other controls dynamically added to it.  Those controls seem to scroll in and out of view nicely without using those offsets.  Go figure....

Thanks, again.

Comment: Controls have an `AutoScrollOffset` property that determines where they're shown in a ScrollableControl Container. -- Use the code that Hans posted, the offsets I've shown in my first comment were meant to describe directly how these values are applied. The `AutoScrollPosition` usage would have been *the answer*, but that's what you can find in that post. -- I'll mark it as duplicate in case it solves your problem (or if you don't post back).