# Drawing Nodes Graphics Paint C#

Tags: c#, scroll, graphics, drawing, shape-outside

**EDIT:** How do I activate scrollbars and maintain my drawing after scrolling, like Paint application. As you can see I'm drawing a circle with 25px radius, outside the client rectangle, but I can't scroll.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Nodes
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.AutoScroll = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(0,this.ClientRectangle.Bottom, 50,50));
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Really, do I need to show some code to get some help? I was editing my post, SAME QUESTION, different way of writing it.

Comment: I understand that this is how the rules on this page are, but ... how do you go about asking something about which there are no courses and you only have the written form to communicate it? Isn't this supposed to be a forum to ask questions or doubts that arise in the day-to-day programming?

Comment: If you have a question on how to ask question on SO (which is not "a forum", but that you probably already know from going trough [tour] and [help]) you should ask on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/. Side note - it is somewhat surprising that no one ever wrote anything about scrolling... maybe searching again https://www.bing.com/search?&q=c%23+set+scrolling+area+winform%20site:stackoverflow.com could reveal some information on the second attempt?

Comment: I searched in different ways and did not find information related to my question. I came to SO with the slightest hope that they would give me a hint, that someone has gone through a similar situation and is able to give me some documentation about it. The rules are too inflexible and it is difficult to ask something "suitable" for OS without having enough information, nor the information available to see it. I appeal to the experience of a colleague to be decisive, not to be told "opinion question". Thank you but SO does not serve me, nor is it practical. Greetings.

Comment: I ask you for some common sense, if I already know the answer, why am I going to ask something on StackOverflow? To help someone who does NOT want to help? Don't you realize that this rule is very inflexible? In that case StackOverflow should not exist, if every time you ask something they send you to get the information and they are not able to give decent answers, then the page does not make sense.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8727320/14171304).

Comment: We need code when a question is not clear enough. What about the 'Nodes' you mention? What do you mean by 'maintain my drawing' ? Keep the position or scroll it?  -  Chances are you would have been pointed the right way right away if you had spent as much time and effort on the question as you did on the comments..

Comment: If I make an scroll down or resize, the content that I drawn does not appear. Dear, I asked a direct question, 100% text explaining the problem, I took half an hour of writing for the other to appear to say "question based on opinions" ... you do not collaborate much either.

Comment: Already solved this question, in other place.